# How do I turn a cats IO into a Effect using http4s

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s

I've got some code that returns an IO but I need a Effect in http4s.

```
import cats.effect.{Effect, IO}

class Service[F[_]: Effect] extends Http4sDsl[F] {
    val service: HttpService[F] = {
        HttpService[F] {
            case GET -> Root =>
                val data: IO[String] = getData()
                data.map(d => Ok(d))
        }
    }
}
```

gives

```
[error]  found   : cats.effect.IO[F[org.http4s.Response[F]]]
[error]  required: F[org.http4s.Response[F]]
[error]         data.map(d => Ok(d))
[error]                 ^
```

Comment: Is there any reason why `F` isn't bounded to `IO` here? Meaning `HttpService[IO]`?

Comment: This is how the http4s template does it. It does work if like `HttpService[IO]`. Im assuming its possible to keep it abstract and better some how. Maybe not.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way we can get around using a concrete `IO[A]` is using [`LiftIO[F]`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/liftio.html):

```
class Service[F[_]: Effect] extends Http4sDsl[F] {
  val service: HttpService[F] = {
    HttpService[F] {
      case GET -> Root =>
        getData().liftIO[F].flatMap(Ok(_))
    }
  }
}
```

`LiftIO` lifts will lift: `IO[A] => F[A]`, but this yields us `F[F[Response[F]`. In order to get things to compile, we'll `flatten` on `F` since it has a `Monad` (or `FlatMap`) instance in cats due to our `Effect` context bounds requirement.

If we want more detail, this is the `-Xprint:typer` result:

```
cats.implicits.catsSyntaxFlatten[F, org.http4s.Response[F]](
   cats.effect.LiftIO.apply[F](Service.this.evidence$1)
                     .liftIO[F[org.http4s.Response[F]]](
                       data.map[F[org.http4s.Response[F]]](
                        ((d: String) => Service.this.http4sOkSyntax(Service.this.Ok)
                          .apply[String](d)(Service.this.evidence$1,
                                            Service.this.stringEncoder[F](
                                              Service.this.evidence$1, Service.this.stringEncoder$default$2[F]))))))(Service.this.evidence$1).flatten(Service.this.evidence$1)
```

And at the end of the world when you want to give a concrete effect, for example `Service[IO]`, we get:

```
val serv: Service[cats.effect.IO] = 
  new Service[cats.effect.IO]()(effect.this.IO.ioConcurrentEffect)
```

Where `ioConcurrentEffect` is the `Effect[IO]` instance.

It seems that all the good stuff is defined at [`org.http4s.syntax.AllSyntax`](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/http4s/syntax/AllSyntax.scala) trait.

Comment: BTW, there's syntax extension for liftIO: `getData().liftIO[F].flatMap(Ok(_))`